# Current_user assignment Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, full-text-search, ransack

I am trying to return the current users created gifts in the controller method below before I search using the Ransack gem, can anyone help with suggesting the correct approach to this?

```
def mygifts

    #Gift = current_user.gifts << Trying to assign constant with current users gifts before ransack search

    @q = Gift.search(params[:q])
    @gifts = @q.result.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 6, :page => params[:page])
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not got experience with the [`ransack` gem](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack), but my gut tells me your trying to overwrite the `Gift` constant is going to cause big problems (name conflict etc)

Have you tried using:

```
@q = current_user.gifts.search(params[:q])
```

Comment: I knew there was a simple solution, thanks that worked, much appreciated.

Comment: No problem sir! Enjoy your weekend!